# selecting then deleting from a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on removing from a database but rather than joining the tables, I select the costume_id(primary key) and try removing that way but it only seems to remove from one table rather than all the tables.  I have tried removing the foreign keys before the primary key but that does not work as well.  Do I have to join the tables then delete or does my way work?

```
   $select =  $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM costumes WHERE $q");
   while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc())
            $db_id = $row["costume_id"];

   $costume = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM costumes WHERE costume_id='$db_id'");
   $costume_row = $costume->fetch_assoc();

   $history = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM history WHERE history_id='$db_id'");
   $history_row = $history->fetch_assoc();

   $location = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM location WHERE location_id='$db_id'");
   $location_row = $location->fetch_assoc();

   $state = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM state WHERE state_id='$db_id'");
   $state_row = $state->fetch_assoc();
```

$q is a substream. In my tables there is:

```
costumes (
  costume_id varchar(10) primary key,
  name varchar(50), 
  is_seperate bool, 
  is_onepeice bool, 
  description text, 
  color varchar(25), 
  material varchar(50), 
  genre varchar(25), 
  gender char(1), 
  size varchar(5)
);
state (
  state_id varchar(10), 
  in_use bool, 
  fixed bool, 
  condition text, 
  foreign key (state_id) references costume(costume_id)
);
history (
  history_id varchar(10), 
  previous_user varchar(20), 
  profession varchar(20), 
  previous_play varchar(50), 
  date date, fixed_previous bool, 
  comments text, 
  foreign key (history_id) references costume (costume_id)
);
location (
  location_id varchar(10), 
  loc_no varchar(10) primary key, 
  room_no varchar(3), 
  foreign key (location_id) references costumes (costume_id)
);
```

My new query for delete is:

```
 $delete = $mysqli->query("DELETE costumes,history,status,location FROM costumes join   history on costumes.costume_id = history.history_id join status on status.status_id join location on location.location_id where costume_id='$db_id'");
```

That query is giving me constraint issues

Comment: Do you have an existing SELECT query you could show us that isn't based on one of our queries. Something that shows how you would have joined all your tables in the past?

Comment: i have not joined any of the tables. when I do the selection there is only one table

Answer (score 3):

You should join your tables within the delete statement. So finish this query and then try it:

```
DELETE costumes, history
FROM costumes JOIN history ON costume.costume_id = history.costume_id
WHERE costume_id = '$db_id';
```

Since I don't know exactly how your tables are structured, you'll have to correct the join syntax to match how you normally join them.  For further help, try editing your question and give us all the field names in your 2 tables.

Comment: I edited the post. it now includes all my tables and what is in the each of the tables

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` attribute of the foreign key. Using this, when you delete a costume, it will remove that custome in the history table as well.

Comment: Good point. If you set up your `foreign key constraints` properly, the related rows in other tables will be deleted when you delete a row from the main table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
DELETE from costumes where costumeid in 
(
Select temp_costume.id from
( Select costume_id as id from table....
) as temp_costume
```

Comment: andrew answer would be better imho